# 100% CPU usage Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We have around 13 devices which sends UDP/TCP packets and nodejs server process these packets and save in mongodb with mongoose. meanwhile another process read from monogodb and show to user. these actions are different by how many packets and clients we have but average is about 100 packets per second.
Problem is after 24 hours CPU usage is about 100% and memory usage is high. Also server gets laggy.

The test server is:
Windows server 2012 R2 standard which runs on VMware ESXI, 
CPU is one real core and two virtual cores, 
Mongodb: version 4.0.10, 
nodejs: version 10.16.0, 
Storage: HDD.

Also node runs form CMD with:

```
node main.js
```

Comment: Maybe this article can help you https://medium.com/@igorkhomenko/troubleshooting-mongodb-100-cpu-load-and-slow-queries-da622c6e1339